# php giving empty variable new content

Tags: php, post

Hello, I have a short question. I would like to reset a variable that is going to be posted:

I will post a variable that comes from an input field. When this variable `$_POST['a'];` is empty, I would like to fill it with new content.

The scheme is like that:

empty variable will be posted -> php recognizes that it is empty -> giving it new content -> echoing out new content.

This is just simple but it doesnt work for me.

So here is what I have:

```
$a = $_POST['a'];

if( empty($a){
    $errors['a'][]="text";
    $a =="new content";
}
```

So if there is someone whould could tell me whats being wrong with this, I really would appreciate. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `$a =="new content";` doesn't look right. You probably want 1 equal sign for an assignment instead of a comparison.

Comment: `=` and `==` is different operators. You should use `=` in assignment and `==` in compassion.

Comment: also tried with === and leaving quotation marks just semicolons...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Three things:

```
$a = isset($_POST['a']) ? $_POST['a'] : ''; // always check if array index exists

if( empty($a)) { // one more bracket
    $errors['a'][]="text";
    $a ="new content"; // only one '='
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have one syntax error in your code, and one logic error.

`if (empty($a) {` is missing an ending `)`

And you're using `==` to do assignments, but it's used for comparisons. You want to use just `=` in this case.

Revised code:

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
if(empty($a)) {
    $errors['a'][] = "text";
    $a = "new content";
}
```

Comment: That won't assign the value of $a to the $_POST variable, which I think the OP is asking for?

Comment: @BenM He's assigning it to `$a` and checking on `$a`, so I'm under the assumption he's never using `$_POST['a']` again.

Comment: @BenM: I think it's just `echo $a;` and not reassigning the $_POST variable

Answer (score -1):

You need to re-assign it in the array if you want to access it by that in the future.

```
$_POST['a'] = $a;
```

Comment: Don't do that, validate the input ant put it into new variables. In your code you should not work directly with input data.

Comment: For what reason may I ask? It would seem best to re-use the memory instead of creating more variables.

Comment: For many many many reasons. You are right, re-using the memory is a good thing. But never trust input. So, don't reuse superglobals. Always put data in new variables. _All input is evil_. By doing so, you will not forget to validate the input.

Comment: One could run a validation foreach on the superglobal, discarding unknowns and validating others. How would you feel about that?

Comment: Better, from security point of view. However, decouple input validation, super-globals and use of input in code is a good idea.